# How Can A L298N DC Motor Controller Module Fry My Rpi?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a fried Pie :(

I used a 12 V power supply to this setup. Can you tell me what I did wrong.

Here is my sample code in python: IN1- gpio18 / IN2 - gpio27 / EN - gpio5

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(IN1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(IN2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(EN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.LOW)
p = GPIO.PWM(EN, 1000)  # set GPIO pin as PWM output, with 1000Hz frequency
try:
    p.start(25)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
    GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.HIGH)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
p.stop()
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Question

> ***Pie fired - Why?***

***Answer***

There is 50% chance that the pins 1, 2, 3 labelled below are hardwired to Gnd or Vcc.  These pins are used for dry run, without Rpi connected.  You use a jumper to short the pair of pins to check out if the motor can move.

But if you connect your Rpi GPIO pins to these dry run test pins, ***Pi fried instantly***.

You might use a multimeter to measure the voltages at these pins, or give me the link to the motor driver to check out the schematics to confirm.

[image: motor driver]

[image: motor driver 2]

Answer (score 2):

You fried your pi because the **V+ is wired to PWR+** so you just sent 12V to your pi. There is not much information about this driver board but there is a thread at the raspberry pi forum and someone even made a schematic of the circuit. You can read more info here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=241060
Appart of V+ being wired to PWR+ there is also an important fact:

> The two enables, ENA and ENB, if left disconnected, default to enabled
> high with 10K pull-ups to Vcc. If you need to control them, the
> IR2104S shutdown inputs enable at 3V rising and 0.8V falling.
>
> The four inputs, IN1A [the first input for bridge A], IN2A, IN1B, and
> IN2B, have 10K pull-downs, and 1.25V thresholds. With this, they are
> 3.3V, 5V, and 12V logic compatible, as long as low is less than the threshold.

I am sorry for your pi but I hope this helps in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with the schematic.

Likely causes.

- connecting more than 3V3 to a GPIO
- connecting more than 3V3 to a 3V3 pin
- connecting more than 5V to a 5V pin

Comment: I think you meant "connect **anything** other than 3.3/5 V to a 3.3/5V pin". E.g. grounding a 3.3V pin is likely to fry the Pi's DC/DC converter.